# Rails 4 strong parameters all of a sudden stopped working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Rails all of a sudden stopped picking up values that are entered with `bootstrap-datpicker-rails`, at least I've only noticed it with dates entered with it.

This is a binding.pry call

```rb
    16: def create
    17:   @batch = Batch.new(batch_params)
 => 18:   binding.pry
    19: 
    20:   if @batch.save
    21:     redirect_to :root
    22:   else
    23:     render 'new'
    24:   end
    25: end

[1] pry(#<BatchesController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/0IzN2EfU7MHWnwLeL/RREsqo3C7vtintD8rbmW4rsbmGhV9Q8crc7DerCAnN+CDZ2Sf4OhSgM1aVl8sl3DLfQ==",
 "batch"=>{"name"=>"Batch3", "date"=>"02/14/2016"},
 "commit"=>"Create New Batch",
 "controller"=>"batches",
 "action"=>"create"}
[2] pry(#<BatchesController>)> @batch
=> #<Batch:0x007f99ca8b1120 id: nil, name: "Batch3", date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, active: nil>
```

As you can see, parameter `batch` has valid date and name values but the `@batch` object only picks up the name and not the date. It was working an hour ago and the only thing I changed were some bootstrap elements for the UI.

My strong parameters:

```rb
  def batch_params
    params.require(:batch).permit(:name, :date)
  end
```

The form for entering the values:

```rb
<div class='well'>
  <%= form_for [@pig, @weight] do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_field :date, "data-provide" => 'datepicker' %>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :weight %>
    <br>
    <%= f.number_field :weight, step: 0.5 %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit(@weight.new_record? ? "Add weight" : "Update weight", class:'btn btn-success') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the type of the `date` column in the database?

Comment: "all of a sudden" and "the only thing I changed were some bootstrap elements for the UI" don't go well together. Have you reversed your changes to see if that "all of a sudden" fixed the problem? Then, if so, you carefully make a single change and see if it breaks again. Once you isolate the problem you can figure out what to do about it. "[mcve]" has good information about this in the final link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails is not able to parse this date format out of the box. But you can add a custom setter to your model to fix that problem:

```
# in app/models/batch.rb
def date=(string)
  write_attribute(:date, DateTime.strptime(string, '%m/%d/%Y'))
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. I have several models using the same date format, so I'd have the same code in several places which seems like code smell to me. Would it be better to switch the column type in the database to `Date` instead of `DateTime`? Is there any drawback to using `Date`? Ruby newbie so I'm not aware of the main differences and drawbacks to the different date classes.

Comment: No, that does not solve your problem. Rails provides the `date_select` helper method and therefore expects a hash with several values (`date(1i)` as the year, `date(2i)` is the month, ...), because that is the format that is returned by the `date_select` method. But the bootstrap date picker returns one string, that does not follow Rails conventions. And if you do not follow Rails conventions then you have to implement the logic yourself that is usually done by Rails' magic...

Comment: So I tried the code but it still errored out, I put a `binding.pry` in the custom setter method but it didn't trigger so I'm guessing that it's not called for some reason in `@batch = Batch.new(batch_params)`. I ended up using `before_filter :some_custom_method` then creating a `DateTime` object in the method by parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the below result,

This is not a valid date to parse `"02/14/2016"`

```
[3] ruby_project »  Date.parse("02/14/2016")
ArgumentError: invalid date
[4] ruby_project »  DateTime.parse("02/14/2016")
[4] ruby_project »  DateTime.parse("02/14/2016")
ArgumentError: invalid date
from (pry):4:in `parse'
[5] ruby_project »
```

Try with valid date and tell me if it works